# How to display by id? codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables:

**EVENTS**

*evid - pk*

evname

evdate

**USERS**

*eventid -  fk*

*userid - pk*

username

**TIME_SIGN**

*userid - fk*

*timeid - pk*

timeDT

---

I want to get the records of the users who have the particular eventid

So in my previous view there is a button to be clicked to view the list of registered users of that particular event.

Controller File: events.php (index)

```
function index()
{
    $data['events'] = $this->model_events->getusersbyid();
    $this->load->view('viewEvents', $data);
}
```

View File: viewEvents.php

```
<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/eventi.png" alt="image-only">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3><?=$event->eventID;?></h3>
                    <h3><?=$event->eventName;?></h3>
                    <h4><?=$event->eventDate;?></h4>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/events/showRegList/".$event->eventID; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Users</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now this part:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/events/showRegList/".$event->eventID; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Users</a>
```

I'm trying to get the ID of the event. Currently, I have only 2 events and 3 users. In Event1 there is User1 and User2 and in Event2 there is only User3. But what happens in the display is it displays all the users. Both, in Event1 and Event2 views.

This is the model for my view file in displaying the records. What am I missing or what could be wrong with my code?

Model File: model_events.php (display_table)

```
function display_table()
{
      $this->db->select("events.eventID, users.id, users.event_id, CONCAT(lname, ', ', fname, ' ', mname) AS name, users.position,  time_sign.indexuser, time_sign.timein, time_sign.timeout");
      $this->db->from('events');
      $this->db->join('users', 'users.event_id = events.eventID', 'LEFT');
      $this->db->join('time_sign', 'time_sign.indexuser = users.id', 'LEFT');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
}
```

This is the view of the list:

```
<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?>
           <tr>
               <td class="hidden"><?=$event->id;?></td>
               <td><?=$event->name;?></td>
               <td><?=$event->position;?></td>
               <td><?=$event->timein;?></td>
               <td><?=$event->timeout;?></td>
               <td width="100px">
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tabledisplay/recTime/".$event->id; ?>">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="time-in" style="margin:3px">Sign In</button>
                   </a>
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tabledisplay/recOut/".$event->id; ?>">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="time-in" style="margin:3px">Sign Out</button>
                   </a>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/events/show_recid/".$event->id; ?>">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                       </button></a>
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/events/delete/".$event->id; ?>">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                       </button></a>
               </td>
           </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is the controller for displaying the list: EVENTS.php

(I put a comment below because that was my idea of getting the ID but doesn't work)

```
function showRegList()
{
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    //$evID = $this->model_events->getusersbyid();
    $data['events'] = $this->model_events->display_table();
    $this->load->view('table_view', $data);
}
```

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are asking correctly, I think you just need to add a where clause to your SQL in the model and pass the event ID to it from the controller script.

First up the Events.php controller script.

```
function showRegList()
 {
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    //$evID = $this->model_events->getusersbyid();
    $data['events'] = $this->model_events->display_table($id);
    $this->load->view('table_view', $data);
 }
```

Second, model_events.php. You will be returning everything because there's no where clause in your statement.

```
function display_table($event_id)
{
  $this->db->select("events.eventID, users.id, users.event_id, CONCAT(lname, ', ', fname, ' ', mname) AS name, users.position,  time_sign.indexuser, time_sign.timein, time_sign.timeout");
  $this->db->from('events');
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.event_id = events.eventID', 'LEFT');
  $this->db->join('time_sign', 'time_sign.indexuser = users.id', 'LEFT');
  $this->db->where('events.evid',$event_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

Hopefully that should get you on the right track.

Comment: Oh my thank you so much I TOTALLY forgot about the WHERE CLAUSE so stupid of me LOL and thanks for pointing out on passing the ID itself in the functions parameter. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try This code **Events Controller**

```
function showRegList()
{
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['events'] = $this->model_events->display_table($id);
    $this->load->view('table_view', $data);
}
```

Model File: **model_events.php** (display_table)

```
    function display_table($id)
    {
          $this->db->select("events.eventID, users.id, users.event_id, CONCAT(lname, ', ', fname, ' ', mname) AS name, users.position,  time_sign.indexuser, time_sign.timein, time_sign.timeout");
          $this->db->from('events');
          $this->db->join('users', 'users.event_id = events.eventID', 'LEFT');
          $this->db->join('time_sign', 'time_sign.indexuser = users.id', 'LEFT');
          $condition=array("events.eventID"=>$id)
          $this->db->where($condition);
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: $this->db->where("events.eventID=$id"); this line produces this error: Unknown column '$event_id' in 'where clause'.... because it reads it as a column and not as a passed parameter. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

okay so that was the result of your modified code. the operator is incorrect. The answer flagged as correct here may help.